# How can I test MySQL statements online?

Tags: mysql, testing

I need a online website to test MySQL statements (some sort of sandbox). Bonus points if you can store code and share it with other people. Something similar to jsfiddle.net for JavaScript. It allows code testing in a safe secure environment.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: @Jon oh tanx.. its works fine

Comment: What is wrong with installing mysql on your PC?

Comment: http://www.compileonline.com/execute_sql_online.php

Comment: http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm?ref=g_wangz

Comment: @Ed Heal i try to answer a question in stack over flow & i need to share code to other guys & i search it in google but i cant find something good...

Comment: Whoa, what's with the downvotes? I believe "software tools commonly used by programmers" is verbatim from the help center.

Comment: @ChristopherW: Not DVed, but probably because it's [braindead easy to discover them yourself](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+like+jsfiddle). People dislike signs of no effort with good reason.

Comment: @Jon tanx a lot, but when you search in google you don`t say sql like jsfiddle?? check jsfiddle keyword.. `mootools,javascript,javascript framework,shell,test` i try to search `mysql online test` but i cant find anything...

Comment: @MehdiYeganeh: I think if you had mentioned that you 'd have gotten fewer downvotes. Also, if a search does not produce results it's far more likely that the search is not good rather than that results do not exist.

Comment: @Jon I know its true but in my mind if i can`t find something in google, i ask it in stackoverflow, because any questions get perfect answer than google with experimental results, tanx again for your answer, its really helps to me..

Comment: @Jon, got it now. Got cleared up by a mod on a flag. This is technically a shopping question. No good on SO.

Comment: sqlfiddle does not work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Theres an sql formatting tool that also reports syntax errors:

http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm

Comment: Tanx, It`s good and i found sqlfiddle.com that offer by Jon in comments